# The GitLab runner using shell executer failures: Job failed (system failure): preparing environment:

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are facing the issue running gitlab-runner on windows server 2016 Datacenter.
It appeared after the upgrade of GitLab to GitLab Enterprise Edition 13.1.8-ee.

We tried to upgrade the gitlab-runner to version 13.6.0 but it didn't resolve that issue.

The error that we are getting:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.1.0 (6214287e)
on Infrastructure NightRun 97hWydn4
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: exit status -1073741502. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

Reset to the gitlab-runner server can resolve it but it will happen again after a week or two.
Any suggestions on how it can be resolved?

Comment: On which OS your runner is running ? What shell do you use ?

Comment: We are running on a Windows server 2016, using shell executer. Once it was cmd and now it's power shell, because CMD shell is deprecated in the last GitLab versions